# Do US → Canada train tickets qualify for entry under VWP?

Tags: usa, canada, esta

We are a family of four from Denmark flying in to California mid July. We will rent a car in LA and travel to Seattle over 3-4 weeks. From Seattle we will mid-August leave USA via train for Vancouver, Canada. We will stay in Vancouver from mid August to January 2016, having a return flight ticket Vancouver-Copenhagen.

If we buy train tickets Seattle-Vancouver before entering USA, will this be sufficient to obtain ESTA?

Comment: Do you mean as evidence of your imminent departure?

Comment: The ESTA application form only asks for your incoming flight details, so it will be granted unless you confess to genocide or something.  All you need to do is convince the immigration officer on arrival that you're going to leave the US.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You just need to show your intention to depart. A train ticket (plus your ticket from Vancouver to Copenhagen) is certainly enough.

In the past, I've bought Greyhound bus tickets from Seattle to Vancouver - they did actually check them and were fine with them as well.  One of the times I did this I was flying into Boston first, and even though it was a bus ticket on the other side of the country, it was fine.

Comment: TO clarify, ESTA grants you the 2 year access. It doesn't ask for proof. However, yes, I was on an ESTA/VWP and had to show the immigration officer my bus tickets on arrival.